# Adding QML file in MDI Subwindow

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm trying to add some qml source file in MDI Subwindow that when I clicked the button we will show subwindow in MDI Area and the display will be the QML source file. Can I possibly add some qml in my MDI Subwindow? . I highly appreciate any kind of answer, suggestion and idea regarding this matter, Thank you.

This is my sample code in adding subwindow in MDI Area, Where can I insert the code for adding qml source file?

```cpp
void MainWindow::on_action_Weather_triggered()
{

    subwindow3 = new QMdiSubWindow(mdiArea);
    widget3 = new QWidget(subwindow3);
    widget3->show();
    subwindow3->setWidget(widget3);
    subwindow3->resize(500,300);
    subwindow3->setWindowTitle("Weather");
    subwindow3->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose,false);
    mdiArea->addSubWindow(subwindow3);
    subwindow3->hide();

    mdiArea->setActiveSubWindow(subwindow3);
    subwindow3->show();
}
```

Comment: Do you have any QML code?

Comment: Yes I have but my problem is on how to set the source file to display my QML file in MDI Subwindow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [`QQuickWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickwidget.html):

***.pro**

```cpp
QT       += quickwidgets
```

***.cpp**

```cpp
QMdiSubWindow *subwindow = new QMdiSubWindow(mdiArea);
QQuickWidget* widget = new QQuickWidget(subwindow);
widget->setResizeMode(QQuickWidget::SizeRootObjectToView);
widget->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
widget->show();
subwindow->setWidget(widget);
subwindow->resize(500,300);
subwindow->setWindowTitle("Weather");
subwindow->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose,false);
mdiArea->addSubWindow(subwindow);
mdiArea->setActiveSubWindow(subwindow);
subwindow->show();
```